# Can i use could in present tense?

Tags: word-usage

I think I have seen could in present tense, "Could you please buy me some fresh apples?" is this usage correct or not?

Comment: Do you mean in the present *time*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is 'could V' always present or future?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/209829/is-could-v-always-present-or-future)

Comment: @EnglishAdam yes, in present time. For eg. someone's in a fruit market and you are asking him on a phone call, if he could/can buy some apples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Could* is possible in present time for two scenarios.

Firstly for polite requests (formality).

> Could you tell me the time?

is more formal than

> Can you tell me the time?

Secondly for unreal scenarios (probability).

> If I could come...

is less probable than

> If I can come...

*Could* for Ability is not possible in the present, *Can* must be used.

> Last year I couldn't swim, now I can.